# what populates data in cataloginventory_stock_status table and from which table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, reindex

In magento2 - I would like to understand what populates data in **cataloginventory_stock_status** table and from which table the data is transferred in this table. I tried searching in **cataloginventory_stock_item** but the data in both table is not matching for **stock_status** and **is_in_stock** fields.